# Choose a sitting order that is fine for all people, with privacy

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, permutation-cycles

I'm looking for a pen and paper algorithm that will output (if possible) a way to sit around a table that is acceptable to all participants, while preserving as much privacy as possible in who finds whom an acceptable neighbor.

More precisely, the input of the algorithm is a positive integer $n$ for the number of people, and a set $A$ of pairs $(a, b) \in Z_n \times Z_n$ (such pair means that $a$ is willing to sit next to $b$.

The pen and paper algorithm must return (if it exists) a cyclic permutation $\sigma$ of $Z_n$ such that:

1. $\sigma(x) \neq x \quad \forall x$
2. $\sigma(a) = b$ implies $(a, b) \in A$ and $(b, a) \in A$

If it doesn't exist the algorithm should say so.

Each participant $x$ decides which tuples $(x, y)$ appear in $A$, and the algorithm should minimize the information that other people can infer, expecially the information about missing couples.

---

The best I've come up with is one person collecting all the tuples, written on individual pieces of paper, and trying to form such a cycle while uncovering a minimal amount of pieces of paper. This is very far from optimal, is there something better?

Comment: The function you're trying to compute is a fixed-width circuit (for fixed n), so cryptographically a very secure version of this is *possible* (though you probably cannot get that degree of security with pen and paper)

Answer (score 3):

One solution, which I think maintains privacy pretty well, but may take a while if A is sparse, would be to just pick random permutations and have a secret ballot vote to see if anyone disapproves of the permutation (where the person opening the votes stops after a single NO vote, so as to make it harder to know the number of people who disapprove).

Comment: This is actually nice! I would expect A to be dense in practice, so this may work. It could also be sped up by generating many options and voting simultaneously!

Comment: What I really like about this solution is that the NO it gives is almost free of any additional information beside "one of the links is not fine"

Comment: It's worth noting that this has one fairly significant information leakage - if the NO vote is the last vote to be opened, then the person who voted NO knows that every link not involving them is in A (and there's also some weaker bayesian version of this that happens on every proposed order that is voted no on), so this can leak a lot of probabilistic info if it takes many proposed permutations to get to one that works.  It also allows people to veto arrangements because of reasons other than their direct neighbors, which is either an upside or downside depending how you see it.

Comment: thanks for your comment! I'm not very worried about information leaking about existing links in the concrete instance I'd like to use it in, but it is an issue in the generic requirements I've described